# how to open an image picker on ipad just in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimage

How can I create the image picker in code?

I use iOS 6.0 , with ARC, for ipad.

I would like to able to select the picture and somehow get UIImage of the selected image.

i did add delegates:
enter code here

in the viewDidLoad method did
`enter code here`imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

and in the button method for click i have put

```
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

the crash happens in

```
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Comment: i have updated the question to explain litle more.

Comment: You can't present this modally on iPad if you are selecting photos from the library. You need to present the picker inside a UIPopoverController.

Comment: Actually, your code works for me.  Your problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: @user1157605 you tested this on an iPhone didn't you.

Comment: @0x7fffffff ahhh yeah, didn't see that until now.

Comment: i tested in ipad simulator.

Comment: i did find any how to do this just in code. Not by using, Storybords

Comment: I have posted code to show you how to implement this

Answer (score 2):

There are some tutorials here http://www.raywenderlich.com/130/how-to-write-a-custom-image-picker-like-uiimagepicker and http://mobileorchard.com/ios-advanced-programming-the-image-picker/ that might help you

Answer (score 0):

I have similar code in one of my projects, but I had

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of

```
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Try that and see if it works.  Note the presentViewController rather than presentModalViewController.

Comment: changing to [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil]; didnt help it crashed as before.

Comment: Yeah, it's because my code was for iphone and you're using ipad.  Not sure about this for ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property in `.h`

`@property (strong) UIPopoverController *pop;`

In you r `.m` file under  your button implimentation add something like:

```
if (self.pop) {
        [self.pop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    }


UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
       imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
       imagePickerController.delegate = self;
       imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES; //if you want to edit the image

       self.pop=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
       //choose the direction of the arrow for the popover
       [self.pop presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
  }
}
```

Make sure you have your `<UIPopoverControllerDelegate>` delegate set in .h

Comment: I have in the .h @interface RayTracerViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
}

than in the .m i have:

self.buttonOne = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
self.buttonOne.frame = CGRectMake(320.0, 20.0, 300.0, 40.0);
[self.buttonOne setTitle:@"off gumb" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.buttonOne addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonPressed1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.view addSubview:self.buttonOne];

and now i did write:

Comment: UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES; //if you want to edit the image
    self.pop=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
[self.pop presentPopoverFromRect:self.buttonOne.bounds inView:self.buttonOne permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

Comment: Grapher2[54097:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'

Comment: first of all if using iPad add <UIPopoverControllerDelegate> that seems to be missing form what your posting

Comment: i did now and the same crash.

Comment: this are the delegates. i have in .h <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>

Comment: add this to the code in m ~if (self.pop) {
            [self.pop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            
        }
~

Comment: didt help, i have the same crash. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.